# How to reduce the size of iOS framework target using on demand resource?

Tags: swift

I have created a framework which contain assets and i have to reduce space of my app size so that i want to used on demand resource to reduce asset size in framework but xcode said

> " On-Demand Resources is enabled (ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES = YES),
>   but is not supported for framework targets"

, framework documentation and on demand resource guide have no clear information either it support or not , is framework support on demand resource app thinning?